# Race condition when dynamically adding websocket handlers

Tags: scala, websocket, netty

I'm writing a websocket with netty and I seem to have a race condition in my code:

I have a channel initializer that builds pipeline consisting of:

```scala
  ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpServerCodec())
  ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536))
  ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyServer())
```

And MyServer works as follows:

- if it receives a websocket upgrade request, it tries to authenticate the request
- if it fails, it returns bad request
- if it succeeds, it tries to:

  - add websocket handlers followed my custom logic handler and finish the handshake and establish webscoket connection
  - it's done using following code:

```scala
      awareLogger.debug(log"upgrading to websocket")(logContext)
      ctx.pipeline()
         .addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(route, true))
         .addLast(new WebSocketFrameAggregator(65536))
         .addLast(new MyWebsocketLogic(logContext))
      ctx.fireChannelRead(httpRequest)
      val _ = awareLogger.debug(log"upgraded to websocket")(logContext)
```

It's trying to `fireChannelRead(httpRequest)` in hopes that `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler` will intercept it and finish the handshake.

My issue is - the `httpRequest` sometimes seems to be propagated all the way down to `MyWebsocketLogic` handler and fails to establish the connection and handshake.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? It's almost like i have some kind of race condition when in the code.

Comment: This code looks perfectly fine... I think you should try to use a debugger to see what's going on

Comment: @NormanMaurer Thanks for the answer. The pipeline modification is done in a different thread than the one that's assigned to the channel (the whole block gets executed in different thread pool) ... do you think that could cause any troubles?

Comment: To add more clarity, the whole block of code that modifies pipeline will be executed on the same thread pool, but on different one that is assigned to the channel thread ... and not just different thread that different threadpool entirely

Comment: I guess that could explain it. Could you try to offload this to the `EventLoop` of the `Channel`. `channel.eventLoop().execute(...)`.

Comment: will try, thank you

Comment: it seems to be working, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that:

```scala
      awareLogger.debug(log"upgrading to websocket")(logContext)
      ctx.pipeline()
         .addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(route, true))
         .addLast(new WebSocketFrameAggregator(65536))
         .addLast(new MyWebsocketLogic(logContext))
      ctx.fireChannelRead(httpRequest)
      val _ = awareLogger.debug(log"upgraded to websocket")(logContext)
```

was called in different thread than the one assigned to given `ctx`.

I was able to fix this by applying suggestion from Norman above, that is switching the pipeline modification to `EventLoop` of the `channel`, meaning:

```scala
      ctx.channel().eventLoop().execute { () =>
        val _ = ctx
          .pipeline()
          .addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(route, true))
          .addLast(new WebSocketFrameAggregator(65536))
          .addLast(buildWebsocketHandler(logContext, connectionHandler))
        val _ = ctx.fireChannelRead(msg)
      }
```

This seems to work well